# Create database, tables etc in one script postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I've a script:

```
CREATE DATABASE ahop

GO

CREATE TABLE shop.dbo.TABLE1 ( 
); 

CREATE TABLE shop.dbo.TABLEN ( 
);
```

But it doesn't seem to work in PostgreSQL. Error message: "error near GO". I dont get it, how to create scripts in Postgresql?

Comment: When i remove "GO" and replace it by ";" I've got an error. Message: "CREATE DATABASE cannot be executed from a function or multi-command string". And the issue is, that i need to execute them all from one script.

Comment: You also can't specify a table with `database.schema.tablename`. But this all documented in the manual.

Comment: the one you showed is for `TSQL`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Replace the T-SQL batch terminator `GO` with the PostgreSQL batch terminator `;`.
`GO` is not supported in postgreSQL

- [Microsoft SQL Server to PostgreSQL Migration by Ian Harding](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server_to_PostgreSQL_Migration_by_Ian_Harding)

you need to connect on the database using `\`. eg,

```
 CREATE DATABASE testdatabase; 
 \c testdatabase 
 CREATE TABLE testtable (testcolumn int);
```

- [PostgreSQL for MySQL users](http://www.coderholic.com/postgresql-for-mysql-users/)

Comment: Please take a look on my comment to main post.

Comment: Is it actually possible to do this without using the psql program?